# How to get value of text in state.when i clicked on TouchableOpacity in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

### How to get value of text in state.when i clicked on TouchableOpacity in react-native ?

I have gender value in text of TouchableOpacity . so I want to get value of selected gender in state when i clicked on TouchableOpacity.

So please help me how i can achieve this functionality.Thank you in advanced.

This is some part of my screen you can see below.

[image]

Comment: is the text in youchable opacity from a variable?

Comment: No.it is simply write in Text component @GauravRoy

Comment: then whats the problem here? if you dont have any variable then you can just plot on the value in onPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function like this

```
setGender=(props)={
  this.setState({gender:props})
}
```

call this function from button onPress like this

```
 onPress={()=>this.setGender("Male")}
 onPress={()=>this.setGender("Female")
```

and show state value in Text

Answer (score 0):

Example Codebase :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gender: "",
      textGender:"Male"
    };
  }

  //Get text value
  getTextValue = () => {
    alert(this.state.gender);
    console.log("Selected Gender is ", this.state.gender);
    console.log("Selected Gender From Text ", this.state.textGender);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.gender}
          keyboardType="default"
          onChangeText={gender => this.setState({ gender })}
        />

        <Text>{this.state.textGender}</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.getTextValue()}
        ></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: I am used only TouchableOpacity for select gender @Akila Devinda

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
onPress = (Male) => {
       this.setState({ gender: 'Male'})
    }
    onPress1 = (Female) => {
       this.setState({ gender: 'Female'})
    }

         <TouchableOpacity
                 style={styles.button}
                 onPress={this.onPress(Male)}
               >
                 <Text> Male </Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>

             <TouchableOpacity
                 style={styles.button}
                 onPress={this.onPress1(Female)}
               >
                 <Text> Female </Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>*
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  };

  onChangeValue = value => {
    if (value !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({
        value: value,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.value.length > 0 ? (
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 40,
              alignSelf: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            {this.state.value}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 40,
              alignSelf: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            I identify as you
          </Text>
        )}
        <Button
          color="#000"
          title="Male"
          onPress={() => this.onChangeValue('male')}
        />
        <Button title="Female" onPress={() => this.onChangeValue('female')} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Feel free for doudts.