# Can't find variable when setting value to selected image in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here are my functions. They check the selected image by the user and assign an ID to them.

```
setCharacter = (props) => {
  this.setState({
    character:props
  })
}

const pressHandler = (character) => {
  this.setCharacter(character)
  console.log(character);
}
```

I'm using the functions here to assign the ID.

```
TouchableOpacity onPress={(pressHandler('1'))}>
            <Image style={{height: 120,
              width: 120, alignSelf: 'center'}} source={require('../assets/characters/001-superhero.png')}
            />
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={(pressHandler('2'))}>
            <Image style={{height: 120,
              width: 120, alignSelf: 'center'}} source={require('../assets/characters/003-superhero.png')}
            />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is my error.

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setCharacter`

Thank you very much in advance! I used another stack overflow link to create this:
[How to get value of text in state.when i clicked on TouchableOpacity in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393652/how-to-get-value-of-text-in-state-when-i-clicked-on-touchableopacity-in-react-na)

I hope I'm following all the rules on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using like

```
const setCharacter = (props) => {
  // .. use state from `useState` for hooks
}

const pressHandler = (character) => {
  setCharacter(character)
  console.log(character);
}

TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler('1')}>
...
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler('2')}>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I changed it to -- const setCharacter = () => {
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState('');
} --  it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. What Nooruddin said -- `onPress` has to point at a function and `(pressHandler('1')` is not a function. Change it to `onPress={()=>pressHandler('1')}`
2. You need to declare `setCharacter` properly, with const or something similar: `const setCharacter = ...`
3. Try replacing `this.setCharacter(character)` with `setCharacter(character)` -- I can't tell for sure if that's an issue but it may be.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having a hard time getting this to work :( I'm quite new to programming so I'm not sure if I understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bind or an arrow function but the below should work.

In your constructor also init the state with the character property.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      character: '',
    };
}
```

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pressHandler.bind(this, '1')}>
```

Then you can just update your state with whatever value you passed from the button press in your case either a 1 or a 2.

```
const pressHandler = (c) => {
 this.setState({character: c});
 console.log(c);
}
```

To use the character that was passed in you would just access it via `this.state.character`

`<Text>Current Image ID: {this.state.character}</Text>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure if I'll be able to use it as I'm trying to not use OO : (.